# Vague Error when running function of C# dll in C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

When I am trying to use a C# dll with C++, I can import it successfully. However, when I run a function, I get this vague error:
`Unhandled exception at 0x76E8C632 in DLL Test Open.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0076F524. occurred`

I've tried searching, but nothing comes up, since it's so vague.

DLL Code:

```
// Interface declaration.
[Guid("32529FAE-6137-4c62-9945-DE4198FA9D1B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Add(int Number1, int Number2, IntPtr results);
};

// Interface implementation.
[Guid("9F2F180D-94A9-47e6-91CC-6BCFABD1DDEB")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("ManagedDLL.ManagedClass")]
public class ManagedClass : ICalculator
{
    public void Add(int Number1, int Number2, IntPtr results)
    {
        long sum = Number1 + Number2;
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(sum, results, false);
    }
}
```

Run Code (C++):

```
int main()
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));

    long lResult = 0;
    long firstNum = 1;
    long secondNum = 2;

    // Call the Add method.
    pICalc->Add(firstNum, secondNum,lResult);


    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: The c++ is using three parameters with the results being the third parameter which is not equivalent to returning the value.  The return value is in the microprocessor AX register while parameters are on the execution stack.

Comment: @jdweng in that case, what should i do?

Comment: Try following :         public void Add(int Number1, int Number2, IntPtr results)
        {
            long sum = Number1 + Number2;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sum, results, false);
        }

Comment: @jdweng Does the C++ code stay the same? VS is telling me the `IntPtr` in C# is just a normal `long` in C++

Comment: IntPtr is 4 bytes of any type.  A long in latest version of Net is 8 bytes for Windows 7 and above.  WindowsXP was 4 byte integers.

Comment: @jdweng In that case, what should I do? Forcing an integer doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: It all depends on this line : pICalc->Add(firstNum, secondNum,lResult);
If you want the value retuned as a parameter then you need pICalc->Add(firstNum, secondNum,&lResult);  If you want it as a return value then use long results = pICalc->Add(firstNum, secondNum);

Comment: @jdweng I've tried using all of them, but they all result in the same error. What do i do?